# Python Django. No URL to redirect to. Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model

Tags: python, django, django-model

Всем привет. Столкнулся с проблемой, которую не могу решить. В моделях прописаны get_absolute_url, но почему-то получаю ошибку: "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model."
Вот код (models.py):

```
class Vendor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    vendor_type = models.ForeignKey('VendorType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('motherboard_vendors')

class VendorType(models.Model):
    class Type(models.IntegerChoices):
        MOTHERBOARD = 1, 'Материнская плата'
        CPU = 2, 'Процессор'
        STORAGE = 3, 'Накопитель памяти'
        VIDEOCARD = 4, 'Видеокарта'
        RAM = 5, 'Оперативная память'
        MONITOR = 6, 'Монитор'
        SOFTWARE = 7, 'Программное обеспечение'
        PROJECTOR = 8, 'Проектор'
        PRINTER = 9, 'Принтер'

    name = models.CharField(choices=Type.choices, max_length=255, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('motherboards')
```

forms.py:

```
class AddMotherboardVendorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vendor
        fields = ['name']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-input'}),
        }

    def clean_name(self):
        name = self.cleaned_data['name']
        if len(name) > 50:
            raise ValidationError("Длина превышает 50 символов")
        return name
    
    def save(self):
        vendor = super().save(commit=False)
        vendor.vendor_type_id = VendorType.Type.MOTHERBOARD
        vendor.save()
        return vendor.get_absolute_url()
```

views.py:

```
class AddMotherboardVendor(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = AddMotherboardVendorForm
    template_name = "home/motherboard/addmotherboardvendor.html"
    title_page = 'Добавление производителя материнской платы'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = self.title_page
        return context
```

urls.py:

```
path('motherboard_vendors/add_motherboard_vendor/', views.AddMotherboardVendor.as_view(), name='add_motherboard_vendor')
```

Раньше была другая сущность Vendor:

```
 class MotherboardVendor(models.Model):
     motherboard_vendor_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')

     def __str__(self):
         return self.motherboard_vendor_name
    
     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse_lazy('motherboard_vendors')
```

Но, как только я её заменил, сразу начала вылетать ошибка: "No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a get_absolute_url method on the Model.". Пробовал удалять базу с миграциями и заново создавать, но ничего нового не увидел. Пересоздавал полностью проект, тоже не помогло. На всех других моделях, где стоит get_absolute_url - всё работает корректно. Может кто сталкивался с таким, и подскажет, в чём проблема?

К форме AddMotherboardVendorForm пробовал добавлять def get_success_url(), но получал ту же ошибку